# How to show a .doc/.docx file in an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

How can I display a .doc/.docx file in an iframe?

i am using :

```
$(htmlId+ ' iframe').attr('src', filePath);
```

Comment: You can't force a `doc` file to be displayed inline. It's up to the browser whether they choose to 1. Display it inline 2. Download it 3. Use an external viewer, or even 4. Ignore it.

Comment: Is the browser you use capable of displaying those files at all?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are plugins available that can manage that. Wouldn't be surprised if IE did it natively, without needing a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Upload it to google docs and then show the gdocs url ... (thats the way gmail does it) ;)